# C# MVC. Использование ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, viewmodel

Добрый вечер!

В проекте ASP.NET MVC есть такой класс:

```
[Table("somedb.data")]
public class DataModel
{
    [Key]
    public int IdData { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(45)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public int AdditionalValue { get; set; }
}
```

В данный класс маппится таблица `data` из базы данных.

Пусть для отображения некоторой веб-страницы `Data` нам нужно только свойство `Value`.

Как должен выглядеть класс `DataModelView` в таком случае? И как должен выглядеть контроллер для отображения данной страницы?

Исходя из моего понимания, все это должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

и

```
public class DataController : Controller
{
    private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext(); // Это класс, унаследованный от класса `DbContext`, обеспечивающий соединение с базой данных, в котором есть виртуальное свойство DbSet<DataModel>

    public ActionResult Index(DataViewModel model)
    {
        model.Value = db.data.Select(d => d.IdData == 1);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Я не знаю, правильно ли я работаю с `ViewModel`-классом. Правильно ли я заполняю данные `model`? или данные модели заполняются в другом месте? Подскажите, правильно ли я делаю? или нужен другой подход?

Comment: Поясните для чего вы передаете `model` в `Index`?

Comment: У вас наверное он с нулл референсом падает, не?

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk я и хотел уточнить это. Как правильно писать контроллер. Видел пару примеров, где в контроллер с атрибутом `HttpPost` передавали `ViewModel`. Но где задавалась `ViewModel` я не знаю.

Comment: @AGS17 этот код я чисто для примера привел. У меня в проекте другие классы и база данных. И там я пока не использовал `ViewModel`, а передавал все во `ViewBag`.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko передают сюда параметры запроса (например, данные для создания чего-либо в бд). Это - входные параметры, с которыми вы будете работать

Comment: В метод вы передаете что-то от пользователя. Если ничего не передается, то зачем писать параметр? А что передать в представление можно самому создать, например `var model = new DataViewModel  { Value = db.data.Select(d => d.IdData == 1) }; return View(model);`

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk я понял, благодарю! А если от пользователя нужно получить заполненный объект `ViewModel`, то где данный объект заполняется? В какой части кода? не во `View` ведь? Извините за такие глупые вопросы, просо я еще совсем сырой в ASP.NET MVC. И можете порекомендовать хорошие статьи по данной технологии? буду очень признателен.

Comment: @Andrei Adam Freeman "Pro ASP.NET MVC"

Comment: @AGS17 извините за глупый вопрос, но где задаются параметры запроса? Я просто пока не использовал запросы клиента.

Comment: Создаете форму и модель привязки. Потом эту модель передаете как параметр в метод.

Comment: В get запросах - в урле (example.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2), в post - в request body (погуглите)

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk Спасибо большое! Это то, что я хотел услышать! И спасибо за литературу!

Comment: @AGS17 спасибо вам за направление меня в нужную сторону! Дальше сам уже)

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk не желаете оформить ответ на вопрос?

Comment: @Andrei хорошо, буду дома - оформлю)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko ответ уже есть. Дублировать нет смысла. Только если что-то другое.

Comment: @Prokopchuk уже нет смысла отвечать, Вы правы. В следующий раз пишите сразу ответ, чтобы другому не достались баллы репутации:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если ты хочешь найти по id и затем вывести DataViewModel на странице, то код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
public class DataController : Controller
{
    private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext(); 

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var data = new DataViewModel 
        {
            Value = db.data.Find(id).Value
        }
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

А код вьюшки так:

```
@model SampleProject.Models.DataViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sample Page";
}
<h4>@Model.Value</h4>
```

Если же ты хочешь вывести все данные, то код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
public class DataController : Controller
{
    private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext(); 

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var list = db.data.Select(x => new DataViewModel 
        {
            Value = x.Value
        }).ToList();
        return View(list);
    }
}
```

А код вьюшки так:

```
@model List<SampleProject.Models.DataViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sample Page";
}
@foreach(var data in Model)
{
    <p>@data.Value</p>
}
```

Рекомендую почитать статьи на сайте **metanit.com**

В частности:

- [ASP.NET MVC 4](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/)
- [Entity Framework](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/)